# Delphi 10.4 Events view not updating during debug

Tags: delphi, event-log, delphi-10.4-sydney, outputdebugstring

I want to use Events View more dynamically.

I use OutputDebugString(PChar(s) and want it to update the events view.

```
s := 'test ' + String(Datetimetostr(now));
OutputDebugString(PChar(s));
```

It works, but the events view does not update dynamically during debug. 
Only after closing view and opening it again with Ctrl+alt+V i can see my outputlines after scrolling to the bottom og the view.

Comment: Delphi 10.4.2? Works fine for me. I have my Messages window docked under the editor in debug mode.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I frequently use OutputDebugString and never noticed what you explain, even with D10.4.2. Maybe you have an application or an IDE extension that capture OutputDebugString output which interfere with the normal behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scroll down to the bottom of the event view in order to see your latest events then it means that at some point in time you have disabled `Scroll new event into view`

So right click on your Events window and select `Properties` and then in the new opened window add check-mark at `Scroll new event into view`

[image: Event Log Properties]

Comment: Thx, That seems to be a reasonable answer, but unfortunately I HAVE enabled it.:)

Comment: So you say that your event log isn't scrolling to the bottom when new events are generated then. Or the problem might be because the events aren't added to event log in real time?